# Rails engine models in Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm working on a rake task for a Rails project which is separated into multiple engines. The task is located in the `lib/tasks` folder of the *main* Rails application, and is attempting to create a new `Post` from the `Blog` engine (`engines/blog/app/models/post`).

The engine file (`blog/lib/blog/engine.rb`) looks like:

```
module Blog
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blog
  end
end
```

So if I'm understanding correctly, referencing `Blog::ModelHere` is the correct syntax. Here's the rake task:

```
namespace :blog do
  desc "Import blog posts from old Wordpress site"
  task :import => :environment do
    # ... generating variables here  
    post = Blog::Post.create!(
        post.title = title,
        post.slug = title.parameterize,
        post.date = date,
        post.user_id = User.find_by_name(user).id,
        post.content = content,
        post.tags = tags
    )
  end
end
```

Returns...
`undefined method 'title=' for nil:NilClass`

It seems to choke on the `Blog::Post` call. I've tried `::Blog::Post` as well, but that didn't seem to make much sense. I've also tried keeping it in `blog/lib/tasks` as an engine task, but I couldn't get that working either.

I've looked around SO and Github to see if anyone has code up for rake tasks within engines, but couldn't find anything concrete. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create! should be accepting a block to perform the assignments, what you have there is doing assignments then passing the result as arguments.

```
post = Blog::Post.create! do |post|
    post.title = title
    post.slug = title.parameterize
    post.date = date
    post.user_id = User.find_by_name(user).id
    post.content = content
    post.tags = tags
end
```

Comment: Awesome. I definitely misread the returned error. You're a lifesaver!